# Any tool to improve contrast of study materials?

Tags: color, packages, accessibility

I see many slides of my study materials which are done by WYSIWYG and colored with many colours to improve the contrast.
To improve contrast with colors, I think is not necessarily the best way to go.
I think this kind of text is difficult to read.

Is there any package which considers the contrast itself or any guidelines how to reach good standard? 
I like myself black-and-white and then just bold, italic and underline rarely.

What colours should be used to improve contrast?

### My final proposal for the solution

Use Mathematica to find the optimum colormap for your presentation, to optimise the contrast for each use case. Include pictures and text in thinking about the colormap.

Comment: You should probably get inspired by the norms of the Internet regarding contrast: WCAG 2.0 and WCAG 1.0. You can have an overview [regarding HTML pages](http://www.checkmycolours.com/) easily.  To get the code of colors in LaTeX, refer to [LaTeX color](http://latexcolor.com/).

Comment: It's generally a good idea to use patterns as well as colour to distinguish regions; e.g `hatched`, `lined`, `dotted`, etc